# javascript effects queue (chain)

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

im building an animation framework for my work, and im stock in the Queue or chain effects part, actually i have something like this:

```
var Fx = {
    animate: function(){...},
    fadeIn: function(){...},
    fadeOut: function(){...}
}
```

etc etc... so, actually i can do:

```
$('#element').animate({options}).fadeIn({options});
```

and it works excellent! but the fadeIn and the animate execute at the same time but what i want to do, is something like:

```
$('#element').chain().animate({options}).fadeIn({options});
```

so it execute the animate first and then the fadeIn

actually i have something like:

```
var Chain = function(element){
 var target = element;
 for (methodName in Fx) {

  (function(methodName) {
    Chain.prototype[methodName] = function() {
     var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return this;
    };
  })(methodName);
 }
}

Fx.chain = function(element){
  return 
    }
```

and i can get all the methods called and that stuff, but i dont know how to push that to an array or even call the first method, because im trying to get all requests to an array and just call it everytime if effects is done.

im not use jQuery, as i said i need to make a personalized framework.

Any idea pleeeasse??! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[Simple Demo](http://jsbin.com/odumi4/18/)**

```
var Fx = {
  animate: function(el, style, duration, after){
    // do animation...
    after();
  },
  fadeIn: function(el, duration, after){
    // do fading ...
    after();
  }, 
  // other effects ...

  chain: function (el) {

    var que = [];
    function callNext() { que.length && que.shift()(); }

    return {
      animate: function(style, duration) {
        que.push(function() {
          Fx.animate(el, style, duration, callNext);
        });
        return this;
      },
      fadeIn: function(duration){
        que.push(function() {
          Fx.fadeIn(el, duration, callNext);
        });
        return this;
      }, // ...
      end: callNext
    };
  }
};
```

*Usage*

```
Fx.chain(el).animate("style", 300).fadeIn(600).animate("style2", 900).end();
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer; wish I could give extra points for providing a demo!

Comment: I tryied, but doesnt seems to work :( it just execute the first method, i mean, in here: chain(el).animate(opts).fadeOut(opts); it just does the animate part, not the fadeOut

Comment: wow, that works in the demo! let me check, maybe is my mistake

Comment: Ok i modified the chain function, so i can call it like: $('#element').chain().animate({opts}).fadeOut({opts}).end(); and doesnt work, :( i'll paste it to jsbin.com thank you for your help!! i'll let you know the link! :D

Comment: I didn't want to past my code into jsbin. A little bit about how you intergrate `Fx` to your framework would've helped. Never mind. I gave you the idea. The rest is up to you.

Comment: Ok, i updated the code, i added how i integrate the Fx with the rest of the code: http://jsbin.com/ecigo3/4/edit  thank you for all your help, im trying to fix it myself.

Comment: I can't see any problem here. Are you sure your animation code is bug free? I would give http://github.com/madrobby/emile a shot. It's 1,5 kB and does every kind of animation.

Comment: Can you help me with a doubt? i dont understand how will the "callNext" function, call all the methods in queue, because i know it have the shift method and is calling it at the end, but i dont see how will it call it a second or third o more time??

Comment: ohh i see my mistake, i forgot to send the "after" function on each request, thank you!! i'm gonna change that! thanks so much!